# Marginaleffects package produces error with nlme

Tags: r, nlme, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

This question just migrated from crossvalidated, as it is indeed more a programming question.
I have tried a lot of things (all kind of way to provide info to the `newdata`-argument), from which I present some below. The summary: everything works with `lme4`, but only the first works with `nlme`.

The question:

I need to use `nlme` rather than `lme4` because I want to be able to account for heteroscedasticity. But for some reason, `comparisons` in the `marginaleffects` package keeps producing the same error, no matter what I try: *Error: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. You can try to supply a different dataset to   the `newdata` argument.*

Below some some toy-data that replicates the problem. Only the first `comparison`-command works, the others all give the error-message.

```
base <- expand.grid(time = 0:5,
            Treat = LETTERS[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

base <- base%>%bind_rows(base, base)%>%group_by(time, Treat)%>%
  mutate(repl = row_number(),
         replicate = sprintf("%s-%s", Treat, repl))%>%ungroup()
re <- data.frame(replicate = unique(base$replicate),
                 re = rnorm(9))
datasim  <- base%>%left_join(re)%>%
  mutate(out = re + rnorm(54, sd = 1 + time))%>%
  mutate(ctime = as.character(time))


fit <- nlme::lme(out ~ ctime*Treat,
                 random = ~ 1| replicate,
                 weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | ctime),
                 data = datasim)

comparisons(fit)

comparisons(fit,
            variables = "Treat")

comparisons(fit,
            variables = list(Treat = "pairwise"))

comparisons(fit,
            variables = list(Treat = "reference"),
            )
comparisons(fit,
            variables = list(Treat = "pairwise"),
            newdata = datagrid(ctime = "5"))

comparisons(fit,
            variables = list(Treat = "pairwise"),
            newdata = datagrid(ctime = "5", model = fit))

comparisons(fit,
            variables = list(Treat = "pairwise"),
            newdata = datagrid(ctime = "5", replicate = "A-1"))
```

If I replace the `lme`-call by an `lmer`-call, all of the comparisons run as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Treat` variable to a factor *before* fitting your model.

This is (arguably) an upstream problem with the handling of character variables in `predict.lme()`, which breaks when `newdata` does not include all levels of the predictor.

Load packages and prep data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(nlme)
library(marginaleffects)
base <- expand.grid(
    time = 0:5,
    Treat = LETTERS[1:3],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
base <- base %>%
    bind_rows(base, base) %>%
    group_by(time, Treat) %>%
    mutate(
        repl = row_number(),
        replicate = sprintf("%s-%s", Treat, repl)) %>%
    ungroup()
re <- data.frame(
    replicate = unique(base$replicate),
    re = rnorm(9))
datasim <- base %>%
    left_join(re, by = "replicate") %>%
    mutate(out = re + rnorm(54, sd = 1 + time)) %>%
    mutate(ctime = as.character(time)) %>%
    mutate(Treat = factor(Treat))
```

Fit model and comparisons:

```r
fit <- nlme::lme(out ~ ctime * Treat,
    random = ~ 1 | replicate,
    weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | ctime),
    data = datasim)

comparisons(fit, variables = "Treat")
# 
#   Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error       z Pr(>|z|)   S  2.5 % 97.5 %
#  Treat    B - A  -0.0365       1.03 -0.0355    0.972 0.0  -2.05  1.978
#  Treat    B - A  -0.9755       1.52 -0.6408    0.522 0.9  -3.96  2.008
#  Treat    B - A   0.9695       2.22  0.4363    0.663 0.6  -3.39  5.325
#  Treat    B - A   0.1212       4.38  0.0277    0.978 0.0  -8.46  8.707
#  Treat    B - A  -6.6345       3.08 -2.1565    0.031 5.0 -12.66 -0.605
# --- 98 rows omitted. See ?avg_comparisons and ?print.marginaleffects --- 
#  Treat    C - A  -1.7364       1.52 -1.1406    0.254 2.0  -4.72  1.247
#  Treat    C - A  -1.7145       2.22 -0.7715    0.440 1.2  -6.07  2.641
#  Treat    C - A   0.2368       4.38  0.0541    0.957 0.1  -8.35  8.823
#  Treat    C - A  -1.4930       3.08 -0.4853    0.627 0.7  -7.52  4.537
#  Treat    C - A   0.5092       6.14  0.0829    0.934 0.1 -11.53 12.551
# Columns: rowid, term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted, out, ctime, Treat, replicate 
# Type:  response
```